# GET passando todos os registros na URL e POST Apresenta apenas o ultimo registro

Tags: php, html, sql

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo certo ?

Estou tentando criar uma página para inserção de itens dentro de um carrinho, essa página guarda o código do cliente e o código da comanda em uma variável e passa ela entre telas, na minha tela de pesquisa de produtos adicionei um botão, onde ao clicar nele, adiciona o produto nessa id que guardei.

Problema: Quando eu deixo o Action do form como `GET`, apresenta todos os registros na `URL`, agora quando eu deixo como `POST`, passa o valor do ultimo registro do banco para variável.

Acredito que haja alguma falha na lógica criada, poderiam me auxiliar ?

OBS: Deixei o código do produto dentro do input para passar como `POST`;

```
<?php if($rows=mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 

    ?>
    <form method="GET" action="incluir_itens.php">
        <!-- Criando os inputs abaixo para incluir o id da comanda e código do cliente, para enviar via POST pra incluir itens, não sei se é o melhor jeito, mas funcionou-->
        <input type="text" name="id_comanda" id="id_comanda" value="<?php echo $id_comanda;?>">
        <input type="text" name="cod_cliente" id="cod_cliente" value="<?php echo $cod_cliente;?>">

        <table id="tabela" class="table table-hover">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th scope="col">Código</th>
                 <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
                 <th scope="col">Qtd</th>
                 <th scope="col">Preço de Venda</th>
                 <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <?php
                 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //while que mostra os resultados
                 ?>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                     <b><input type="text" name="cod_produto" id="cod_produto" value="<?php echo $rows['cod_produto']; ?>"></b>
                </td>
                    <div class="col-5">
                            <button type="submit" style="border:none;"><i class="fa fa-check" style="font-size:25px;color:green;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                 </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                 }
                 mysqli_close($conn);
                 ?>
           </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

URL como GET: `/incluir_itens.php?id_comanda=32&cod_cliente=2&cod_produto=1&quantidade=&cod_produto=2&quantidade=&cod_produto=3&quantidade=&cod_produto=4&quantidade=&cod_produto=5&quantidade=`

SQL Utilizado:

```
session_start();
   include('conexao.php');

   $tipo_pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa_produto'];
   $valor_pesquisa = $_POST['valor_pesquisa'];



   if ($tipo_pesquisa == "descricao"){
       $sql_produtos = "select * from produtos where descricao like '%$valor_pesquisa%'";
   }
   elseif($tipo_pesquisa == "cod_produto"){
       $sql_produtos = "select * from produtos where cod_produto = $valor_pesquisa";
   }
   elseif($tipo_pesquisa == "cod_interno"){
       $sql_produtos = "select * from produtos where cod_interno = '$valor_pesquisa'";
   }

   $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql_produtos);
```

Se deixo como `POST`, apresenta apenas o ultimo registro do meu banco.
**Se no meu registro do banco apresenta somente 1 registro, consigo incluir no carrinho normalmente.**

Answer (score 0):

Isso se deve por que existem vários inputs com o mesmo `name`. Tente trocar de:

```php
<b><input type="text" name="cod_produto" id="cod_produto" value="<?php echo $rows['cod_produto']; ?>"></b>
```

Para:

```php
<b><input type="text" name="cod_produto[]" id="cod_produto" value="<?php echo $rows['cod_produto']; ?>"></b>
```

Comment: Opa Tiago, obrigado pela ajuda !!
Tentei dessa forma, porém continua puxando todos os produtos.
Dentro do [ ] eu adiciono alguma variável de controle ou algo assim ?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o trecho do SQL.

Comment: Feito a edição Tiago ... Obrigado !

Comment: Ótimo, quando você envia ao PHP campos com o nome contento `[]`, você está dizendo que está enviando um array. Neste caso, você tem que alterar o seu SQL: `$sql_produtos = "select * from produtos where cod_produto IN (".implode(',', $valor_pesquisa).")";`

Comment: Obrigado Tiago pelo retorno...
O que acho estranho, é que o incidente ocorre apenas quando eu tento incluir o produto no carrinho, no caso quando o action é executado... O Select em si ocorre tudo certo, porém acredito que o problema esteja no name dos campos mesmo, pois como está tudo igual, sistema puxa o valor de todos os campos...
Vou tentar fazer o que vc fez e também incluir uma logica para altera o "name" conforme linhas, por exemplo:
Linha 1: name="codigo_produto1" e assim por diante.

Pois quando no select trás apenas 1 item, consigo inserir no carrinho normalmente.

Comment: Opa Tiago,
Estava verificando e se eu mudo o Botão por um href, passa todos os parâmetros certinho, somente daquela linha, porém o action do botão envia o formulário inteiro, todos os registros...

Comment: No HTML quando você tem um elemento `button` do tipo `submit` dentro das tags `form`, ao clicar esse formulário será enviado.

Comment: Que bom que você gostou das respostas! Mas a melhor forma de agradecer a quem te ajudou é assinalando "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo. Adicionar uma nova resposta assim (que não é uma resposta pra pergunta e deve ser removida) deixa o site mais confuso e pode atrapalhar.

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver.
O que ocorre é que conforme mencionado pelo Tiago, como eu estava enviando um SUBMIT para o POST ou GET, normal enviar o formulário inteiro.

Minha solução foi a seguinte, criei um link ao lado da linha, puxando o código do produto, direcionando para uma página onde só apresenta aquele produto e um campo de quantidade, de forma que ai sim eu possa executar o post que enviará apenas aquele produto.